# Upper bound of $\left| \sum_{n=1}^N e^{2\pi i\psi(n+1)} \right|$, where $\psi(x)$ is the digamma function

Tags: reference-request, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, exponential-sum, digamma-function

Let $\psi(x)$ the digamma function, see its definition and relation with harmonic functions from this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).

> **Question.** I am interested about if is known how to find an upper bound of $$ \left| \sum_{n=1}^N e^{2\pi i\psi(n+1)} \right|, \tag{1}$$ as $\leq N\Delta$, where $\Delta=\Delta(N)$ is little and satisfies $\Delta(N)\to 0$ as $N\to\infty$. **Thanks you in advance.**

I've created this question and has no more context, to know what are the method and approach that you can use.

Comment: Can you find a non-trivial upper bound for $$\left|\sum_{n=1}^{N}e^{2\pi i\log(n)}\right|$$ ? $\log(n)$ (just like $\psi(n+1)$) is slowly increasing.

Comment: Now I don't know how to find such non-trivial upper bound. Obviously I know that my sum is related to harmonic numbers $H_n$, with $n\geq 1$.  Maybe I can to search what about the example that you are saying @JackD'Aurizio (how works the example with the logarithm).

Comment: As a rule of thumb, it is best to be able to tackle simple problems before wondering about more complex ones. Exponential sums are very important in additive number theory, I suggest you to have a look at Vinogradov - *The method of trigonometrical sums in the theory of numbers*.

Comment: I was interested in this example because it is the same example that the exponential sum for harmonic numbers $H_n$. Many thanks @JackD'Aurizio